# Why is my Facebook login not accepting the code from Google Authenticator 2FA?

Tags: facebook, google-2fa

How can I fix facebook login with 2fa and google authenticator when the code from google authenticator is not accepted to login to facebook.

It was working as recently as last night.  I have google authenticator on my phone configured for the same email I use for facebook.

The help doesn't help as it is talking about actions to take once you are logged in.

I expect there is a way to seek help but the facebook help screens do not have a link.